# WPF TextBlock requirement

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a requirement for my textblock to have a character gap of 75 and a border line of 2 pixel. How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For spacing the characters out you could look at the following:
[WPF TextBlock: How to evenly space displayed characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476311/wpf-textblock-how-to-evenly-space-displayed-characters)

For border line, i guess wrapping it around the Border element should do the trick.

Hope it helps you or atleast gets you started on the right track.