# Option to give all characters an equal width/space

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I created an table where in one column I display 8 characters per line. Since they are not equally spaced it looks very odd.

Since Iam set to a Font that doesnt support the "FontStretch" option, this isnt a possible solution for my situation.

Is there another option to achieve something similar so that all characters have the same width?

I found this solution, but it doesnt seem very smooth and considering its age I hope that a better option was implemented over the years.
[WPF TextBlock: How to evenly space displayed characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476311/wpf-textblock-how-to-evenly-space-displayed-characters)

Comment: An alternative might be an ItemsControl which has the text string assigned to its ItemsSource. It will however not look any better then the control in the answer to the original question.

Comment: Hi, its worth a shot, i guess. I will update the question in case I find any good way. Sofar no luck unforunatly. But Thanks :)

Comment: Use `<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>` as ItemsPanel and an ItemContainerStyle with a Setter for the Width and `<Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a monospaced font like Courier or Consolas.

Comment: hi, unfortunatly Iam not allowed to change the font. Its part of a biger project with multiple people.